# TEMPORARY table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

If two users create two TEMPORARY tables at the same time in my mysql database using a PHP script, will it create two different tables? Can those users use their own table without facing any trouble and will those table be automatically deleted?

thanks :)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable ( ID int, Name char(100) ) TYPE=HEAP;
INSERT INTO TempTable VALUES( 1, "Foo bar" );
SELECT * FROM TempTable;
DROP TABLE TempTable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary tables are created in a current session; so, two users can create two temp. tables at the same time in their threads. These tables will be removed on session closing.

Comment: but how does it work if two users create two TEMPORARY tables at the same time using the same table name? Thanks :)

Comment: Temp. tables are session scoped objects. You can create some tables with the same name using different connections.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> A `TEMPORARY` table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-`TEMPORARY` table of the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table is dropped.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[IF NOT EXISTS]` in this query...
[reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/create-table.html)

Comment: so if I use `[IF NOT EXISTS]` and the db already has the same table name, will it not create the table by replacing the table name with something? thanks :)

Comment: I just found this information in this website http://zez.org/article/articleview/54/ that " heavy loaded sites will not have a problem with using the same table name since it's unique per connection." Could you please explain me what this line is actually saying?